# How to disable the new "Auto Cascade-View" feature of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, window, coordinates

### Scenario

I'm using **Windows 10** (build number **10240**)

As all **Windows 10** users noted, the new operating system of *Microsoft* comes with a new aesthetic change in its Explorer.

In earlier versions of **Windows**, all Explorer windows that we close and reopen are shown exactly at the same last position where we hadd closed them, but now, in **Windows 10** all the windows opened by Explorer will be shown automatically in Cascade View, producing this effect:

[image]

...and it seems imposible to disable it in a natural way.

This bug, or better said this annonying design decission its very frustrating for the user experience because in short words now a **Windows 10** user can't keep a personalizaed order of the position of the Explorer windows, because if we close one, when we reopen the same window or open a new one its coordinates will be different to produce the annonying cascade view.

In this video I demonstrate this problem taken to the extreme:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uoFuVtqKdY

---

### Question

After the necesary explanations given above to understand what I'm talking about and prevent confussions of any kind, I will launch my question:

- Is there a built-in solution to disable this behavior of **Windows 10**? or is there any kind of registry hack or resource file patch/modification to disable the automatic cascade view?. Or other apporach?.
- Optionally: Is there any anounce from Microsoft employers, a windows update, or a public ISO release that reveals a future fix for this?.

In other words, I would like to use the same behavior as earlier versions of **Windows**, I won't use this cascade view.

---

### Research

I tested a lot of 3rd party applications but any of them has convinced me, because all has very bad inconvenients.

I know **ShellFolderFix**, which can be downloaded here:

http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html

... But **ShellFolderFix** its more a troublemaker than a fix, because it has a annonying bug that causes the current Explorer window to "randomly" move over the screen. I describe the bug and the steps to reproduce it here:

http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/7566-remember-window-position-13.html#post421870

Then, **ShellFolderFix** or other window managers are not an option for me, I'm asking for a proper solution that does not involves the usage in background of those kind of applications.

### Update

I heard that the build **10525** of Windows 10, which seems it was released on **12/October/2015**, it fixes the cascade view. However, it is an Insider Preview and I cannot find the ISO in my native language, in Spanish.

Comment: this happens since Windows 7. Have you moved from XP to Win10?

Comment: This doesn't happens in Windows 7 neither in Windows 8 or Windows 8.1. At least on my Windows builds, the explorer windows always are opened in the same position on which I close the window (without any annonying cascade view effect). I didn't moved from XP to Windows 10, I have realized a clean installation of the Windows 10 ISO release in a Virtual Machine. Thanks for comment!

Comment: @magicandre1981 As for I read in other websites, I heard that It's possible that in your case if you have the "Snap" feature enabled then it is which could be producing a cascade effect when opening explorer windows. Windows 7/8/8.1 by deault does not produce a cascade view.

Comment: for me it happens and this why tools like ShellFolderFix were created when Win7 was released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said a recent Insider Preview build fixes your issue.

You don't need an ISO to join Insider Preview or to install updates. You simply sign up (it's free) and then make some changes to your Windows Update settings.

[Here](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5050/windows-10-tip-get-new-features-and-updates-faster) is a link to instructions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Anyways, seems there is any Spanish language pack to download.